# How can I parse a quoted string with Parsers.jl

Tags: julia

Julia’s CSV.jl parses csv files with quoted strings. It uses Parsers.jl to do this. Yet from the documentation of Parsers.jl it is not clear how to parse a double-quoted string on its own. How would I do that? As a secondary question, what is the supported set of escape sequences that Parsers.jl uses?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arbitrary characters to indicate quotation and escape characters via `Parsers.Options`. For example,

```
using Parsers

str = "{-1}"
oq, cq, e = UInt8('{'), UInt8('}'), UInt8('\\')

res = Parsers.xparse(Int64, str; openquotechar=oq, closequotechar=cq, escapechar=e)
x, code, tlen = res.val, res.code, res.tlen
print(x)
```

Comment: Right. Thank you. But what if I want to parse a string, rather than an Int64. That doesn’t seem to be supported.

Comment: You can parse a string as well. For example, `res = Parsers.xparse(String, "\"this is a text\",")`.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your example above (or the example with String). Julia reports that res is a tuple and has no field val.